# Update does not work in Laravel, If I use different textbox name than column name in database

Tags: laravel, validation, model, eloquent, laravel-5.5

My table country has two fields `country_id` and `country_name`.

the textbox is using name `country`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Session::get('name')}}" name="country" >
```

CountryCOntroller code is

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 $this->validate($request, [
 'country' => 'required|country_name',
  ]);
   $updateCountry = $request->all();

    //update  data
    country::find($id)->update($updateCountry);
    return redirect('/admin/country');
}
```

my model is

```
 class country extends Model
{
protected $table = 'country';
protected $fillable = ['country_name'];
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = 'country_id';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the name in the input filed to `country_name` as it should match the column name so it should be like this,

`<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Session::get('name')}}" name="country_name" >`

If you don't want to change that then you should change you controller where you send the array in to the `update` method. so something like this,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 $this->validate($request, [
 'country' => 'required',
  ]);


    //update  data
    country::find($id)->update([
'country_name' => $request->country
]);
    return redirect('/admin/country');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Most of such things are not available on laravel documentation, how do you learn?

Comment: I can't really remember this particular thing but [DevMarketer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6kwT7-jjZHHF1s7vCfg2CA) channel helped me a lot.

Comment: why it works only with unique:country,country_name' .i want to use it without unique

Comment: Yes course, you can! can't remember why I put that there! Let me edit the question

Comment: How ? please tell me

Comment: it just not work simiply, textbox name must be same as field name but i want to use different

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
country::find($id)->update([
    'country_name' => $request->country
]);
```